June 2024 photo competition Kites
The topic is "Kites", suggested by Bernhard.
Photos with one or more kites are welcome. This can be the big festival kites, big enough to lift several people, small ones kids play with, even miniature fun ones. If you do not have a photo with a kite in it but with something related you can send that in instead.
Remember that if your photo includes people (other than you), you need permission (from them) prior to posting the photo. Alternatively, you can make them unrecognizable.
The contest will end at the end of June (UTC time). The following rules apply:

Up to three photos per answer. Photos in the same answer should be related.
You can make up to three posts (attempts).
Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.) Text edits are acceptable.
All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
Keep it nice, CoC-compliant, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
If you disagree with a photo, please consider commenting on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
The photo may have been taken any time.

If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.
If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the list of possible photo competition topics. Also, you can join us in chat to help us decide which topic to choose.
MattAllegro wins the vote, hkotsubo wins the virtual prize.

I have this photo that has a kite in it, but it's so far in the sky that we can't barely see it. Do you think it qualifies for the competition?

YES!!! And if others disagree on the kite it still has something related, the line going up.

Picture posted, thanks!

That's my brother teaching his son how to fly a kite (and - hopefully - how to avoid the electric cables).
The wind really helped that day, the kite is so high we can't barely see it. But Willeke said the picture qualifies for the competition :-)
Taken in Marília, Brazil, in December 2015.


Note for counting the votes, someone has ignored the 'no downvotes' rule.

This looks like a potential Darwin Award.

@jcklopp Fortunately, nobody got injured that day :-)

You got as many votes as the highest voted one till the last moment, you get the virtual prize, also because I like this photo, it has a kite but you can hardly see it.

@Willeke Wow, I wasn't really expecting winning this, what a nice surprise! Thanks a lot!

Kite and wind festival 2023, held in the surroundings of St. Dimitri chapel in Għarb, Gozo (Malta).
Some more of my photos here!




You have the highest voted photo and as such you win the bragging rights.

@Willeke I just typed "bragging" into WordReference and still laughing ;) Thank you all for the votes :)

It was the time of Makar Sankranti, a Hindu festival that is associated with flying kites (and battle thereof) in the Western part of India. Me and my friend were home away from home, working in the lion city of Singapore.
We somehow wanted to fly a kite and caught a wind that the Marina Barrage is a popular (and allowed, you don't want to get fined in Singapore) place to do so. So off we went and enjoyed flying this red smiley in the cool wind, clear skies and many children wanting to get a hold of our kite. Missed the battles, but the view was totally worth it.
One can easily view the Marina Bay Sands, the Gardens by the Bay(including its Supertree grove), the Singapore flyer and downtown Singapore.




Taken by me on the outskirts of Kampala (Uganda) in January 2014.


Took this picture of a kitesurfer on 2011/07/21 at Matadouro Beach in Ericeira Portugal
canon eos 400D, f11, 100mm, ISO100, 1/200


Kite borders on Kailua Bay, Hawaii in January of 2021.



I bought a book with a kite kit many years ago and haven't yet put it together and tried it. So here it is in its box which comes with a book how to fly it.
Photo taken today 15 June 2024, in the Netherlands.


I was in Amsterdam today and in the shop Flying Tiger I saw these kites, with permission of the staff member at the till I took this photo, expressly to post in this competition.
Photo taken 15 June 2024, Amsterdam, the Netherlands.

Pictures taken by me at a kite festival in East Anglia, UK, in March 2007.
The first picture is a detail of the bear seen in the second picture, with an echo of kite strings in an airliner's contrail.



For the sake of sharing (and landscapes), although I had already posted one photo from this set of mine a few months ago.
Kite(surfer)s at Tarifa beach in July 2022, nofilter pictures taken with Samsung A50 phone.




Can we go home, please?
Taken by me in September 2007 in UK.

